# Parsing SQL to find a specific string in Sqlite

Tags: parsing, sqlite

I have an Sqlite column that gives me information in the form of

`208|iMessage;-;+12555555555|45|3|188235574-A320-44F9-AA20-4F234B078|bplist00?_%com.apple.iChat.LastArchivedMessageID?_$9757B765-A1FF-4C80-AC8C-7C3BB7220AAF|+1975510555|iMessage||example@gmail.com|0|+12834444444||C56467F2-5318-46B0-8D33-36B93D16608F`

And I'm just trying to parse each of these 208 similar lines to find the phone number in this segment: `|iMessage;-;+12555555555|`

I have tried using 
`select substr('iMessage;-;', charindex('iMessage;-;'+11),11) from chat;`

but charindex isn't supported in sqlite3. I also tried `select substr('iMessage;-;', instr(select * from chat;, ’iMessage;-;'),11) from chat;` but this gave me a hanging prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you put each value in its own column?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I'm relatively new to SQL, so I think a column would be Car type: Ford, Dodge, Ram, Mercedes. Is that correct?

Comment: Does the | between each entry denote a column?

Comment: In the `sqlite3` command-line shell, `|` indeed is the column separator. Do all rows have the same format? Do all values in this column begin with `iMessage;-;`?